# How to fetch image from online database (given class)?

Tags: python, image

I am working on a personal (non-commercial) project. For one reason or another I need a bunch of images from a given class. I know there are big databases out there such as ImageNet or Laion 5B. I was wondering if anoyone knows/has heard a way how I could fetch an image from such an online database via an API call. (Everything in python)

I was wondering if something like this exists:

```
from Laion import getRandomImageFromLaion 
image = getRandomImageFromLaion(class = 'cat')
```

This would be extremely helpful. I know I can download the datasets onto my computer but they are usually vast and I don't think I have memory for it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
import pathlib
import shutil
import pandas as pd
import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

IMAGE_DIR = pathlib.Path('images')
LABEL = 'dog'  # <- Change here

url = 'https://knn.laion.ai/knn-service'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0',
}
payload = {
   'modality': 'image',
   'num_images': 40,
   'indice_name': 'laion5B-L-14',
}
r = requests.post(url, json=payload|{'text': LABEL}, headers=headers)
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json())


# Download images from dataframe url
(IMAGE_DIR / LABEL).mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
for img in df['url']:
    try:
        r = requests.get(img, stream=True)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            img = pathlib.Path(img)
            with open(IMAGE_DIR / LABEL / img.name, 'wb') as fp:
                shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, fp)
    except ConnectionError:
        pass
```